# memoir class hide page number on title page with table of contents

Tags: titles

I am trying to start a new document with the memoir class. I would like to have the title page display the table of contents as well. Right now, I am trying this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,article,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\title{Generic Title}
\pretitle{\thispage{empty}\begin{center}  \Huge \bfseries}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\centering \Large  \textit{Generic subtitle}\par}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents*
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the `\thispagestyle{empty}`-command has no affect, and I am still seeing a small page number on the front page.

I found out that if I disable `\tableofcontents*`, then the page number disappears as well.

While this is only a minor annoyance - is there any good way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`\maketitle` issues `\thispagestyle{title}` overwriting your earlier `empty`. Just alias the `title` style to empty:

```
\aliaspagestyle{title}{empty}
```

Comment: is there a specific place where i should put this? because right now, it is not working...

Comment: @Razupaltuff update your question with your current code